# Find the radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a real positive sequence. Suppose $$\dfrac{a_{n+1}a_{n-1}}{a_n^2}\to l, l\ge0,l\not=1$$

Find radius of convergence of $\sum a_n z^n$.

I have no idea about the condition. I guess I'm supposed to divide the sequence into even and odd terms but I failed. Someone give me a hint?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: Idea:$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}a_{n-1}}{a_n^2}=\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$$

Comment: @Khosrotash I noticed it and it is the reason that I tried to divide the sequence, but I didn't get it.

Comment: $$\dfrac{a_{n+1}a_{n-1}}{a_n^2}=\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$$ 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=k \to 
\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}=\dfrac1k$$

Comment: @Khosrotash But actually neither of them have to converge...

Comment: Oh.sorry .You are right

Comment: @Khosrotash It's fine. Great idea:)

Comment: Which method(s) do you know to characterize the radius of convergence of a series? We will never know... and the game continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r_n:=a_{n} /a_{n-1}$. By assumption, $r_n=r_{n-1}l\left(1 +\varepsilon_n\right)$, where $\lim_{n\to  +\infty}\varepsilon_n=0$.

- If $l\gt 1$, there exists $n_0$ such that $l\left(1 +\varepsilon_n\right)\gt (l+1)/2\gt 1  $ for $n\geqslant n_0$ hence $r_n\to  +\infty$.
- If $l\lt 1$, there exists $n_0$ such that $l\left(1 +\varepsilon_n\right)\lt (l+1)/2\lt 1  $ for $n\geqslant n_0$ hence $r_n\to  0$.

Conclude by the ratio test.